# Artikel oder ohne ihn?

Tags: grammaticality, article

Ich habe den Text geschrieben, um eine Grafik zu beschreiben:

> Die folgenden statistischen Informationen über die deutschen Berufstätigten sagen aus, dass am meisten Teilnehmer, die sich an Weiterbildungsseminaren beteiligen, aus öffentlichem Dienst kommen.

Müsste es eigentlich „aus dem öffentlichen Dienst“ sein? Es gibt aber nur einen öffentlichen Dienst.

Comment: Es müsste in diesem Fall _aus öffentlich**em** Dienst_ heissen. Mit Artikel: _aus dem öffentlich**en** Dienst_ .

Comment: Danke für das Korrigieren. Ich habe es bearbeitet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja, es sollte *aus **dem** öffentliche**n** Dienst* heißen. Ich würde allerdings den ganzen Satz umformulieren:

> Die folgende Statistik über deutsche Berufstätige besagt, dass die meisten Teilnehmer an Weiterbildungsseminaren aus dem öffentlichen Dienst kommen.

Das Hauptproblem des ursprünglichen Satzes liegt in der Phrase

> dass am meisten Teilnehmer [...] aus dem öffentlichen Dienst kommen.

Darin wird nämlich das Wort *Teilnehmer* betont; zudem heißt *am meisten* nichts anderes als *überwiegend*. Die Aussage lautet demnach, es kämen überwiegend Teilnehmer, nicht jedoch andere an Weiterbildungsseminaren Beteiligte (wie etwa Ausrichtende, Catering-Mitarbeiter und dergleichen), aus dem öffentlichen Dienst. Ich bezweifle, dass diese Aussage gemeint war.

Comment: Wenn ich meinen Aufsatz weiterschreibe: „Etwa ein Drittel kommen auch aus der Industrie, dem Handel und letzendlich dem Handwerk.“  Also sollen alle diesen Begriffe einen bestimmten Artikel haben? Es fällt mir schwer, um zu entscheiden ob sie ihn brauchen oder nicht.

Comment: Es geht in dem Fall beides, weil es sich ja um ungezählte Abstrakta handelt. Ohne Kontext klingt _aus Industrie, Handel, und Handwerk_ genauso OK, aber zwecks Konsistenz mit dem öffentlichen Dienst würde ich beim Artikel bleiben (und _aus öffentlichem Dienst_ hört sich hier ohne Artikel falsch an).

Comment: Dem stimme ich zu.